# Count Number of minimum corner paths in a GRID with blocking and multiple queries

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

I can't figure out a good approach to solve this contest problem.

Its [statement](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1742) in resume is.

Given a grid **N**x**M** (1 ≤ N, M ≤ 1000), **H** that represent "holes" in that grid (0 ≤ H ≤ 100) where the borders inside it can't be traversed, and **Q** (1 ≤ Q ≤ 100) queries where each one has a begin point (**xi**,**yi**) and an end point (**xf**,**yf**). Print for each query the number of minimum paths from (xi,yi) to (xf,yf). As this number can be huge, use mod 10^9 + 7 to avoid overflow.

**Input**

> The input is composed of several test cases and ends with end of file. Each one describes a map and starts with three integers N, M and H, which are, respectively, the size of the grid and the number of holes. Then, follows H lines, each with four integers xi, yi, xf and yf describing the bottom left and the upper right corners of a hole. Next follows a integer Q , the number of queries. Then, follows Q lines, each with four integers xi, yi, xf and yf, which are the starting point and the ending point as described above. Between consecutive tests, there is a blank line. It is guaranteed that in a single map, all the holes are disjoint and there is always at least one way to get out.

Example of input:

> 10 10 0
>   3
>   0 0 10 10
>   0 1 9 10
>   5 5 5 5
>
> 6 6 2
>   1 0 2 2
>   3 2 5 4
>   1
>   0 1 4 5

**Output**

> Your program must output one line for each query with the number of ways (mod 10^9 + 7) to get from (xi,yi) to (xf,yf) with minimum moves.

Example of output:

> 184756
>   48620
>   1
>
> 46

BFS on this problem needs memory. A math approach (combinations) seems to fail with the blocking corners. So dynamic programming seems the best. But, i can't figure out how to cope with multiple queries ...

Comment: It's not clear how that picture represents squares with "blocking corners"; it looks more like 5 blocked *edges*.

Comment: i will edit for a clearer description of the problem.

Comment: It's a very hard problem relating to Dijkstra algorithm and DP. It takes hours to write code and explain it in details...